# Why is this text not centered?

Tags: bash, alignment

I've been making a Bash script that says "Made by: Keegan Kuhn" in the banner upon loading. However, I can't get the text to center.

In the beginning, I define some colors to make multicolored text:

```
# Defines colors
black='tput setaf 0'
red='tput setaf 1'
green='tput setaf 2'
yellow='tput setaf 3'
purple='tput setaf 4'
pink='tput setaf 5'
skyBlue='tput setaf 6'
white='tput setaf 7'
grey='tput setaf 8'
```

The part where I have the problem is in the last few lines:

```
string="Disguise your MAC Address as that of any manufacturer as you want."
sleep .2; printf "%*s\n" $(( ( ${#string} + $(tput cols) ) / 2 )) "$string" # Centers variable "string"
echo
string="$($skyBlue)Made by:$($green) Keegan Kuhn ($($red)keeganjk$($green))"
sleep .2; printf "%*s\n" $(( ( ${#string} + $(tput cols) ) / 2 )) "$string" # Centers variable "string"
```

Why is the text sitting to the left and not centering?

Comment: Is it just the second string that isn't centred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "real" string has extra length caused by color definitions, but these definitions are not shown in terminal. Each definition has length 12, you have 4 definitions, so 12x4=48, 48/2=24. Change last line to

```
sleep .2; printf "%*s\n" $(( ( ${#string} + 24 + $(tput cols) ) / 2 )) "$string" # Centers variable "string"
```